# UIImageView Aspect Fill not filling view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I selected Aspect Fill under View > Mode for my UIImageView in my XIB but it stubbornly shows the same sized image.

```
I                   I
I                   I
I   MY IMAGE HERE   I
I                   I
I                   I
```

i.e. there is blank space above and below `MY IMAGE`.

What could I be doing wrong?

==== UPDATE

With a red backgroundColor:

```
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
I   MY IMAGE HERE   I
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

Shouldn't Aspect Fill make it more like the entire rectangle is filled by something like `MAG` where `MY I` and `E HERE` are off-screen.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could programatically set the contentMode of the UIImageView to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill in didLayoutSubviews of your viewcontroller.  (Should fix the problem..)

Are you assigning it a contentMode elsewhere in code perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Doh. Turned out to be something stupid but I'm posting it here in case it saves someone hours of debugging.

Turned out I had AspectFill in the XIB and then AspectFit in my code (which trumped the XIB).

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the *UIImageView* to fill the screen?

If you specfify the mode you change the way the actual image will be displayed inside the imageView. But if your UIImageView does not fill the entire screen the embedded image will too not fill the screen neither.

You should specify the layout constraints to align the imageView with the bounds of its superView.

*A easy way to test this is setting the backgroundColor of the UIImageView to something different than transparent - that way you can see where the image and where the imageView are*

Comment: Updated my question with a red backgroundColor.

Comment: Okay, that Is strange! Does your image have opacity near the edges? That way it would appear the wrong size but actually beeing displayed correctly

Comment: What do you mean by opacity near the edges?

Comment: Is it transparent, pngs have 4 channels, red green blue and alpha. If your image is transparent you could be perceiving its actual dimension incorrectly. But if I think about it then the red would have to shine trough. Could you maybe include a screenshot instead of the ascii art!?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to help debug this is to add a border. My issue was the image that design provided actually had a clear border around it. Chances are you're sizing it right and there's something wrong with the image itself.

Answer (score -2):

I was experiencing a very similar problem only with a horizontally scrolling UIScrollView.

I had constraints on the scrollview and the UIImageView(s) loaded into the scrollview did not aspect fill properly.

Upon removing the constraints on the scrollview, `.scaleAspectFill` worked as it should.